# localized version of GetFileTitle?

Tags: windows-7, file, localization, metadata

I am desperately attempting to guess how the localized filename for photos can be retrieved given the path to that file. For instance, given the path

c:\images\jellyfish.png  - Win 7 explorer and the built in image viewer program both display the word "Méduses" for a french win 7. Does this hold true for other versions of windows ?

GetFileTitle only removes the extension and folder path giving me 'jellyfish' which is not what I am after, and after having read through MSDN and google it seems that the Windows Media Format's http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd798508(v=VS.85).aspx interface wouldn't help here. Either I have lost my googling skills or this is very poorly documented. Help please ?

thank you

Comment: If you look at the extended properties (F stop, camera maker etc) of a jpg (using Windows Explorer in Windows 7) they include a Title property. I think that's what you're seeing in the image viewer. I would feel more confident about this if the title for the jellyfish picture in Sample Pictures wasn't blank for my installation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure about this case specifically (I've never encountered localized filenames in that form) but the only officially supported way I know of to get the localized filenames for system directories and the standard Windows applets, etc., is to use IShellFolder::GetDisplayNameOf.

So briefly, you need to get a PIDL for the file (SHParseDisplayName), bind to its parent folder (SHBindToParent), and then query for the display name using the SHGDN_INFOLDER flag.

Addendum: An even easier way (which I completely forgot about) is to use SHGetFileInfo to get the display name with the SHGFI_DISPLAYNAME flag. This means you don't need to muck around with PIDLs. SHGetFileInfo is essentially a wrapper around the various shell COM classes like IShellFolder - either way, the key is to use the shell to get the display name rather than the underlying API functions.

Comment: Hey, that was most insightful! Although I have not tried it exactly as you have described, you have lead me on the right track :) Please modify it so that it uses HRESULT hr = SHGetFileInfo(tcFilename, -1, &sfi, sizeof(sfi), SHGFI_DISPLAYNAME); which reveals the name I was after. I did not try your exact steps because they seemed redundant to me. I mean, SHParseDisplayName followed by a GetDisplayNameOf both seem to refer to the same thing - the 'display name' that must be fed to the first function a priori (therefore must be already known - not my case). Thanks!

Comment: You're right that SHGetFileInfo can do the same thing, I usually use the underlying COM interfaces and so forgot about that. The SHParseDisplayName function is a bit of a misnomer as what it actually parses is a "parsing name" - see the docs on IShellFolder::GetDisplayNameOf for the distinction (specifically, the SHGDN_FORPARSING flag).