# How is Windows doing secret hide of real file names on sample pictures?

Tags: windows, windows-shell

In windows 7 and earlier versions there is a folder when you install the os called "Voorbeeld Afbeelding" in dutch or translated "Sample images". Nothing ordinary and I use it often as dummy images.

Today I was working on an machine in my native language dutch and one file is called "Woestijn.jpg". If I went to an upload form it told me after browsing to the file it is called "Desert.jpg". In the property's of the file there is nothing about the englisch translation etc.

Listing the files in this directory using the command line it tells the english/real names but in the file explorer it won't show a sign of it.

I couldn't find anything about it on google. There where some links about people getting bugs when deleting files inside this folder, I guess because of the weird name hack (http://forums.adobe.com/message/2862994).

Did the windows programmers used some secret symlink hack to make those files?

Comment: Related:  [localized version of GetFileTitle?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4250580)

Comment: A yes, should have searched better with different keywords than sample images. Also marked it as duplicated

Answer (score 0):

It may be the case that Windows regional settings didn't applied completely.
The word Desert is an English word, where as the word Woestijn is a Dutch word which is an equivalent of the word Desert.

in short:
Woestijn (Dutch) === Desert (English)

so possibility is that Windows explorer is showing content in your native language that is Dutch where as dialogue boxes and command prompt are still working with default language of Windows OS that is English.